# Django static files and require.js. Relative path?

Tags: django, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm wondering if this is possible. I'm currently serving a restful api via Django and Tastypie, with endpoints used by a Backbone frontend app. I'm coming from a Node + Express background and I'm familiar with how Express routes static files. In express, I would be able to do the following:

```
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and access my static files from the public directory. I could access `/public/css/style.css` I would simply browse to `localhost:5000/css/style.css`. In Django, however, the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app utilizes absolute paths. My static files are found at `localhost:5000/User/.../css/style.css` rather than the Express version noted above. This convention would be fine, except for the fact that I am using Require.js for modularizing my Backbone app. No matter how I set my baseUrl, my Backbone app cannot find my modules because of Django's use of absolute paths for servings static files. Is there any way to mitigate this issue in a manner similar to Express' implementation? Essentially, I want Django to route my static files to `localhost:5000/static/...`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Normally you should be able to serve it from `/static/**/*` if you're using the `{% static %}` tag. Could you post your settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line to your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

In your `settings.py` you can have something like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Now you'll get your static files from `base url/static/...`
But you should be careful, this is not recommended for production - [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/)